# Jquery: add delay to then

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery .then to load my scripts sequentially. However the instant bombardment on the server CPU is still way too high. I have tried adding .delay after the .then like so:

```
siteVisits()
    .then(siteTerms)
    .delay(30000)
    .then(siteSources)
    .delay(30000)
    .then(siteBrowsers)
    .delay(30000)
    .then(siteCountries)
    .delay(30000)
    .then(siteContent);
```

However I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'delay'
```

Has anyone got any ideas how I can add a delay before each function is called?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Delay only works with animations.  You can't just use it anywhere.  I'm curious to see how this goes as it will be difficult to introduce delays (setTimeout) into functions chained this way.

Comment: I gathered that from the error, When I said 'how I can add a delay before each function is called' I meant has anyone got any ideas how to achieve this another way?

Comment: I would look into what those functions are doing that is so intensive for the server and optimise them. Waiting 2 minutes for the page to load fully (as your code would have done if it worked) is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @MarkP The error obviously just means that that object does not have a method called delay.  I was just further explaining that.

Comment: Can you tell us what the functions are doing?  I'm assuming something asynchronous, hence the use of promises.

Comment: A better way would probably be to put all your static content on a separate server (or multiple separate servers), optimized for delivering static content -- so no support for server-side scripts etc. That helps tremendously. Have a look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/249512/fastest-web-server-for-serving-static-content

Comment: The functions are calling data from Google Analytics and Converting them into Charts

Answer (score 0):

That's not like .delay works, that should be used to delay an ANIMATION only, for this kind f delay you will have to use setTimeout();

```
siteVisits()
    .then(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            siteTerms.then(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    siteTerms.then()
                }, 30000);
            })
        }, 30000);
     });
```

But why that delay?

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to use deferreds here, they have been created for an entirely different problem. Don't shoehorn delays into them just because you like the fancy syntax.

```
function DelayedExecutor(delay) {
    var self = this, queue = [], id;

    function runNext() {
        var def = queue.shift();
        if (def && typeof def.func === "function") {
            def.func.apply(def.context, def.args);
        }
        if (queue.length === 0) {
            id = clearInterval(id);
        }
    }

    this.add = function (func, args, context) {
        queue.push({func: func, args: args, context: context});
        if (!id) {
            id = setInterval(runNext, delay);
            runNext();
        }
        return self;
    };
}
```

and

```
var de = new DelayedExecutor(30000);  /* new and improved model! */
de.add(siteTerms /*, [arguments], thisArg */);
de.add(siteSources);
de.add(siteBrowsers).add(siteCountries).add(siteContent);
```